# Horizontal line between a question and comments

Tags: support, design

On Stackoverflow there is a horizontal line between a question and comments. This is an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369026/how-to-remove-header-new-line-character-and

And on Unix & Linux there is no a horizontal line between a question and comments:

[How can a bash script detect if it is running in the background?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118462/how-can-a-bash-script-detect-if-it-is-running-in-the-background)

Is it by intention? It seems that it would look better with the horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

This is because our desing layout is a "bar" with buttons

[image]

instead of a line with tabs

[image]

The line in any case would be redundant, since there's already a element that does this.